# array append and conversion to numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

here's my code:

```
z=12
co=0
for x in range(1900,2050):
        z=x*z
        co += 1
        b= [1, 2011, co, z]

        #conversion start 
        b=np.array(b) 
        c.append(b)   
        d=np.array(c) 
        #conversion end
```

as example the first value in b array in the loop is `[1, 2011, 1, 22800 ]`

after first conversion line(b=np.array(b)) b becomes `[     1   2011      4 156755]`

c looks like

```
[array([    1,  2011,     1, 22800]), array([     1,   2011,      2, 22812]), array([     1,   2011,      3, 22824]), array([     1,   2011,      4, 22836])]
```

example of d after 4 loops:

```
[[     1   2011      1  22800]
 [     1   2011      2 22812]
 [     1   2011      3 22824]
 [     1   2011      4 22836]]
```

I need to change the code in the conversion part so that the output d array has the same format as the one in the example. Now what the code does is create the a array from b, then append that array to c and then convert c to a numpy array.
Is there a way to do this faster? Since all this code is in a big loop (not shown), it takes a lot of time to create, append and convert to generate the d array. And I can't move that code outside that huge loop, and the math is just for explanation purpose :)

Thank you

Comment: Why not use numpy to generate the `d` array? Jakevdp's [book](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/02.02-The-Basics-Of-NumPy-Arrays.ipynb) is a good starter on how `numpy` works

Comment: Thank you @Maarten Fabré, do you have something specific in mind? The link you gave me is wonderful, my problem is I don't have time to read it and test it... :(

Comment: Instead of zxbca can you just tell us what you are trying to accomplish, in words?

Comment: The code in the #conversion part is too slow, I'd like to find another way to have as output the `d` array without converting an array `c`, just simply generate `d` from `b`. I can not explain you all the code i'm writing, it will take ages, sorry. Simplified: I have the `b` array and every loop cycle I want to add it to the `d` one. Important: the format of the `d` array must be the one shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we recommend accumulating values in a list, and creating the array once, at the end:

```
In [16]: c=[]
    ...: z=12
    ...: co=0
    ...: for x in range(1900,1904):
    ...:         z=x*z
    ...:         co += 1
    ...:         b= [1, 2011, co, z]
    ...:         c.append(b)
    ...:     
In [17]: c
Out[17]: 
[[1, 2011, 1, 22800],
 [1, 2011, 2, 43342800],
 [1, 2011, 3, 82438005600],
 [1, 2011, 4, 156879524656800]]
In [18]: np.array(c)
Out[18]: 
array([[              1,            2011,               1,           22800],
       [              1,            2011,               2,        43342800],
       [              1,            2011,               3, 82438005600],
       [              1,            2011,               4, 156879524656800]], dtype=int64)
```

Your `z` calculation is unrealistic, growing very large - too large for 'int64'.